# Is there any difference between start appium server via appium & command or using just appium

Tags: npm, appium

I can start the appium server via command line using below commands via command line since I installed the appium using npm.

```
   appium &
   appium

//To change the default port 
appium & --port 9090 
appium  --port 9090
```

As I observed both commands are doing the same, so are they identical or is there any difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `appium &`

`appium &` runs Appium in a subshell.

Consequences:

- You cannot easily quit out of that Appium session (with `control + c` for example.
- Since you cannot quit them, you'll have to close the entire terminal to close the session so you may run into more errors like this:

```
Could not start REST http interface listener. The requested port may already be in use. Please make sure there is no other instance of this server running already.
Fatal Error: listen EADDRINUSE 127.0.0.1:4723
```

This is why I recommend **not** doing this locally. (I think on CI this is fine)

2. `appium`

`appium` runs Appium in your terminal session and essentially "locks" that process to that shell. This makes it so you can easily `control + c` to quit the program on MacOS. I recommend this locally.